# Can someone translate this excerpt?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, translation

Could someone translate the following [from Rashi's commentary](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.24a.18?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.24a.18.1&lang2=bi) on the Talmud:

> במחשכים הושיבני - שאין נוחין זה עם זה ותלמודם ספק בידם

I'm interested in what Rashi has to say regarding Rabbi Yirmeya's statement in the Talmud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translation is as follows:

> **במחשכים הושיבני** - שאין נוחין זה עם זה ותלמודם ספק בידם
>
> **He has made me dwell in the dark places** - i.e. they are not agreeable,<sup>1</sup> this one with that one, and their learning is doubtful in their hands.

So he is saying that the learning in Bavel (Babylonia) is not as clear as that of those in Israel as they are always in a state of argument.

---

<sup>1</sup> Refer to [Eiruvin 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.13b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for a similar application of the word "נוחין"

Comment: Don't you mean "they aren't agreeable"? In Eruvin we don't see that Beis Hillel accepted the opinion of Beis Shamai so much (not that it never happens), rather that even when they argued Beis Hillel would give respect to the opinion of Beis Shamai.

Comment: @Mordechai - yes thank you, I have edited.