# What does this blessing say?

Tags: blessing, translation

[image]

Besides the obvious 5784 in the top right corner :) , what does this blessing say?

Comment: This seems off-topic.

Comment: Who wrote it, if we may ask

Comment: I see now that this is off-topic, but thanks anyway for answering it.

Comment: The 'translation' tag-description implies that it is on-topic: "Questions about translation in general, or about translation of specific words in Jewish texts.

Comment: @Shababnik I can see how you came to that conclusion, though I would personally read/understand that tag differently. It is my understanding that generic translation requests are off-topic, whereas translation requests of Jewish texts and sources are on-topic. For example [this question was off-topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-does-this-tattoo-say), and [this was on-topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120787/can-someone-translate-this-excerpt). You can always ask on the [Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/) to get some consensus.

Comment: @Shababnik Try applying that logic to the [tag:christianity] tag. More generally, that we have a tag for questions about a certain topic doesn't imply all questions about that topic are on-topic (eg. [tag:rainbows] [tag:internet] [tag:statistics])

Comment: I posed the question on [Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5559/33217)...

Comment: I think this question is off-topic, and the answer to the Meta-question confirms it. If the admins would like to delete the question, I appreciate it. If that is okay. @DoubleAA. I was wondering whether it would be on-topic, but now I'm losing points.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that this is off topic. The text presented is plausibly a priori Judaism related.

Comment: @Shmuel The context of the message in the question is definitely a custom. Not Jewish per se being as writing letters to the recipient of a gift is a not founded in judaism. Though one could argue that since it contains vernacular used in Hebrew coupled with the fact that this is probably a note written in a sefer it could be considered on-topic?

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA. Blessing one's fellow can certainly be an expression of Judaism. I think the question post ought to spell out why the asker suspects that this text is an expression of Judaism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

לכבוד ידידי הנעלה מי"ה (ירום הודו) ר' שמואל נ"י (נרו יאיר) ברכה והצלחה.

In honor of my exalted friend Rabbi Shmuel, may his light shine (addendum of blessing to the name of a living person), blessings and success.

Comment: Ty very much :)

Comment: You're welcome very much

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort, but I think this question is off-topic